# entered dateTime by user in c#

Tags: c#, class, datetime

I want to let user enter date and time by classes and DateTime method.At first I want to let user just enter a date of hire without time.

```
Console.Write("Please enter date Of hire");
DateTime dateOfHire = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

then send `dateOfHire` to a method in another calss, Mothod is :

```
public DateTime DateOfHire
{
        set { }
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine( dateOfHire.ToString("D")); // output: 24, december 2042
        }
}
```

I got an error in `get{}` because I have to using `return` how can I use it? if I wrote
 `return dateOfHire.ToString("D");` I get error too.

Comment: return type of DateOfHire property is DateTime and you are returning string. You should check the compiler error closely it should be descriptive enough to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Its probably not a good idea to do user IO inside a property getter

Comment: @gp. the error message is: 'Employee.DateOfHire.get': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You're trying to create a property, but your setter doesn't do anything and your getter doesn't return anything. I suggest you review what properties are in C# - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: If you just want to print a given date, make a static method in your class such as `public static void PrintDate(DateTime date)` and put your `WriteLine` statement inside.

Comment: Error message is clear enough. You need to return and return DateTime type object. Do just this : `get { return dateOfHire; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written it, `DateOfHire` is not a method, it is a property. The property is trying to act on a local member variable called `dateOfHire` which does not exist in scope. So, no wonder you are getting an error.

Try changing `DateOfHire` to a proper method. You will need to pass your local value of `dateOfHire` (obtained from `Parse()`) into the method using a parameter.

```
public void DateOfHire(DateTime dateOfHire)
{
   Console.WriteLine(dateOfHire.ToString("D"));
}
```

Also, `DateOfHire` cannot have a return type of `DateTime` like your property defines. This is because you aren't returning anything, you are simply writing the result to the console. So for your method, the `void` return type is implied.